# What does "Boomps-a-daisy" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have no idea what it means.

I googled and found it seems to be a kind of dance, featured by two dancer bumping their hips?

How to interpret “Boomps-a-daisy” word by word？

Answer (score 4):

[This site](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-ups1.htm) says (of *upsidaisy, upsa-daisy, upsy-daisy, and oops-a-daisy,* etc.)

> These days, it’s just a nonsense word. It’s said to a child as encouragement to get up again after falling over, or when somebody is picking it up.

But it wouldn't surprise me if the origin (or at least, a factor contributing to its survival) involved alliteration with *upside-downside*. Parents also say it when holding a small child up by the hands, and playfully spinning them head-over-heels and back again.

The addition of an initial ***B*** just shifts from regretful/mock-scarey ***Oops!*** towards ***Bump!*** Which suits certain kinds of (childish?!) hip-bumping dance styles.

---

Thus it's pretty pointless even trying to "interpret" the *original* forms (collectively, the utterance just means something like [*"Whee!"*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whee)). And the later "dance" usage is really just a "play on words".

Comment: Note that *bump* is pronounced *boomp* in most Northern UK regional dialects.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is simply a set of mime motions associated with a popular Music Hall song of the 1930s.  It was considered very daring at the time.  See a modern rendition at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ICduCPzqYs

Answer (score -1):

Boomps -a-daisy ... Make cat walk with daisy flower in hand.

Meaning enjoying a wonderful and happy span of time.